How to Convert a Single Line to Heading in Tiptap React Editor Without Changing the Entire Paragraph?
I'm using the Tiptap editor in a React project and I'm facing an issue with converting a single line of a paragraph to a heading. When I try to convert a single line to a heading, the entire paragraph is converted instead. Here's what I'm doing:
I have a paragraph of text.
I select a single line within that paragraph.
I attempt to convert just the selected line to a heading (e.g., ).
However, instead of just the selected line, the entire paragraph is being converted into a heading.
Here are some additional details:
I'm using the latest version of Tiptap and React.
extensions
Color.configure({ types: [TextStyle.name, ListItem.name] }),
TextStyle,
TextStyleExtended,
StarterKit.configure({
 bulletList: {
   keepMarks: true,
   keepAttributes: false, // TODO : Making this as `false` becase marks are not preserved when I try to preserve attrs, awaiting a bit of help
 },
 orderedList: {
   keepMarks: true,
   keepAttributes: false, // TODO : Making this as `false` becase marks are not preserved when I try to preserve attrs, awaiting a bit of help
 },
 // heading: {
 //   levels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 // },
 // paragraph: {},
}),
Image.configure({
 allowBase64: true,
}),
Link.configure({
 openOnClick: false,
 autolink: true,
}),
Code,
];

Editor
export default function Editor(props: Props) {
  const { content, setFieldValue, isEdit } = props;
  if (isEdit && content.length === 0) return <>...loading</>;
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        border: "1px solid #E5E5E5",
        borderRadius: "8px",
      }}
    >
      <EditorProvider
        slotBefore={<MenuBar />}
        extensions={extensions}
        content={content}
        onUpdate={({ editor }) => {
          setFieldValue("content", editor.getHTML());
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}

